# C file descriptor, Poll and thread

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

Assume I have couple of sockets I want to monitor. If I create POSIX file descriptors on each of them and assign an event handler to each file descriptor structure, Do I need to create and assign thread to each socket?

My understanding is that whenever an event occurs on a defined file descriptor, its event handler function will be called. So threads are not required. Am I right?

Comment: My understanding is that threads are never *required*. Sometimes they can improve performance (parallel computing), sometimes they make life easier and many times harder (unless used wisely).  Threads are definitely not *required* to handle multiple sockets but might be a good design choice depending on the application. And please elaborate on "event handler". Without context this is a too broad term. In fact an event handler is just a callback subroutine.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign an event handler to each file descriptor structure"? There are no means of assigning event handlers in POSIX. Creating one thread per one socket is only one of ways to watch for multiple sockets simultaneously. Usually, this is the most simple approach to debug, but it doesn't scale well with lots of sockets. Other options include: 1) use single thread with non-blocking sockets, checking all of sockets one by one in cycle; 2) use single thread with non-blocking sockets and `select`/`poll`/`epoll` syscalls.

Comment: Thanks. I created a structure for each file descriptor that stores a pointer to handler function. Of course is not standard and in POSIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to your question "Do I need to create and assign thread to each socket?" is "No". Threads are perfect way to shoot yourself in the foot.

But look at this part: *"[...] whenever an event occurs on a defined file descriptor, its event handler function will be called [...]"*. And now answer the questions: **Who** will call the event handler? **How** your program would notice, that an event occurred?

Of course you can make every thread for every descriptor and just "sit" on them with e.g. blocking read function. And then die a terrifying death trying to synchronize with your main thread.

But better solution is to make one of your main-loop steps to **check for events** (e.g. using `select` or `poll` functions), and then, for every descriptor that is "active" to call it's handler from the main-loop. If the processing in the handler is not time-consuming you can stay away from the threads at a safe distance.

Comment: "check for events" yes, but use `poll` or `ppoll` which are far more modern and easier to use than `select`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you. I've updated my answer. But I'm used to using `select` ;)

Comment: Thanks. I actually used Poll. But it was my first time to use it and was not sure how it's actually functioning.